# Is it possible to use const_cast on array to change elements?

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, const-cast

This is more of an academic question since I know to generally avoid `const_cast`.

But I was working on the exercise in Chapter 3, # 27 of Thinking in C++, Vol. 1.

> Create a const array of double and a volatile array of double. Index
>   through each array and use const_cast to cast each element to
>   non-const and non-volatile, respectively, and assign a value to each
>   element.

I see how to `const_cast` single vars:

```
const int i = 0;
int* j = const_cast<int*>(&i);

*j = 1;    // compiles and runs
```

But can't figure out how to get it to work with an array. The following compiles, but throws a 'bad access' exception, as if `const` is still there.

```
const int sz = 10;
const double cd[sz] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
volatile double vd[sz] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};

double* cdp = const_cast<double*>(cd);
double* vdp = const_cast<double*>(vd);

cdp[0] = 99;    // bad access error
```

Where have I got it wrong?

Comment: You can't modify something that is const.  lying to the compiler doesn't make it just work.

Comment: Both your examples exhibit undefined behavior. "Compiles and runs" is one possible manifestation of undefined behavior; "bad access error" is another.   See also: [nasal demons](http://www.catb.org/jargon/html/N/nasal-demons.html). A book that suggests it's a good idea to write code exhibiting UB is, shall we say, not a very good book to study C++ from.

Comment: `*j = 1;    // compiles and runs` .. but what does `cout << i` and `cout << *j` print?

Comment: The book is ancient, and it suggest NOT using const_cast in general. Just wanted to solve the puzzle if possible :-)

Comment: Also, where did you get the book from? There is _no_ chapter 32 .. You can grab a copy of it online free, but yes it's ancient (published in 2000)

Comment: cout << *j = 1. Running a for loop on *(cdp + i) prints out array elements as expected.

Comment: `const_cast` purpose is to cast away `const` when you know that either (1) the item being pointed to won't me modified anyway (2) when the item being pointed to is actually mutable. Both cases typically occur when a workaround for ugly APIs is necessary, for example some of C APIs accept only pointers to mutable items, but modify them only when a certain flags are passed.

Answer (score 2):

Please note:

```
const int i = 0;
int* j = const_cast<int*>(&i); 

*j = 1;    // UNDEFINED BEHAVIOR - modify actually const data
```

You are **not** allowed to modify an object by casting away constness that was initially declared as const.  The compiler may place the contents of the object (or array, in your case) in read-only memory which is enforced at a lower level in the machine than the compiler.  When you write, it may trigger a fault.  If it's declared const, you must honor that forever, or get crashes as you're experiencing.

It's *only* ok to modify after casting away constness if the object was initially declared non-const.  (That is, the constness was added later, perhaps as a reference parameter to a function.)

Let's rephrase your question into at least a valid situation for the sake of example.

```
// f() takes a reference to an array, but add constness
void f(const double(&arr)[10]) 
{
    // Here it's ok to cast away constness and modify since the 
    // underlying object isn't declared const (though in general a
    // function doesn't know that about its caller, except in 
    // constrained situations.)
    double * array = const_cast<double*>(arr);
    array[1] = 99;
}

int main() 
{
    // NOTE: array is NOT CONST
    double arr[10] {0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    f(arr);
}
```

And this is fine.

Comment: This is incorrect.  It's perfectly fine to cast away constness of any const pointer you have, regardless of what that pointer points to.  Your reasoning doesn't apply; hardware restrictions do not come into play with such operations.  It's only UB to _modify_ a const object, with the exception mutable subobjects.  IOW, the line you marked as UB is in fact perfectly fine; the next line, `*j = 1;`, is UB.

Comment: Thanks @HWalters, I tightened the bolts in answer at your prompting.  :)